# Writing the QComboBox text into a file

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I'm trying to write a list of bookmarks to a text file. I managed to import a preloaded text file in a browser but I managed to export.

This is my function:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionExport_bookmarks_triggered()
{
   QString bookmarks = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Please save file");

   if(!bookmarks.isEmpty())   
   {
       ebookmarks = bookmarks;
       QFile StringBookmark(bookmarks);

       if (StringBookmark.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
       {
           QTextStream out (&StringBookmark);

           for (int i = 0; i < ui->comboBox->currentIndex(); i++)
           {
               out << ui->comboBox->currentText();
           }

        }
        StringBookmark.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be something like this instead:

```
[..]
for (int i = 0; i < ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
{
    out << ui->comboBox->itemText(i) << endl;
}
```

The problem was that you always print the current text.

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm! Do you know how I could get the each piece of data to store on a new line in the txt?

Comment: @user3099916, you can simply append a new line character '\n' after each combo box item text. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was always thought that was only applicable within quotations for some reason.